# How to use RxJS from Chrome Extensions service worker?

Tags: rxjs, bundling-and-minification, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, umd

I am able to successfully use RxJs 7.8.0 from my Chrome Extension's `popup.js` and `options.js` by importing RxJS from their corresponding `popup.html` and `options.html` files like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./libs/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="options.js"></script>
```

However, I also have `background.js` from which I would like to use RxJs. This is service worker and does not have html file. So when I try to import RxJs like this:

```
import * as rxjs from "./libs/rxjs.umd.js";
```

My chrome extension gets following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'rxjs')
libs/rxjs.umd.js:416 (anonymous function)
```

Which corresponds to following code:

```
413:(function (global, factory) {
414:    typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? factory(exports) :
415:    typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define('rxjs', ['exports'], factory) :
416:    (factory((global.rxjs = {})));
417:}(this, (function (exports) { 'use strict';
```

I am able to successfully import other libraries from my `background.js` file. So this seems to be something specific to RxJs. If it matters I got RxJs from [this CDN](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.8.0/rxjs.umd.js)

Comment: This is not a ES module so you shouldn't really import it directly. Instead you should build it using a bundler like webpack or find a proper ES module version of this script. If you want to import it directly nevertheless the workaround is to add `self.module = {exports: self.exports = {}};` to js file that is imported before rxjs, then use `exports`.

Comment: @wOxxOm I did the workaround.The error I am getting now is "Uncaught TypeError: rxjs.combineLatest is not a function" when from background.js file I do `rxjs.combineLatest(...)`

Comment: Actually, if I use exports.combineLatest instead of rxjs.combineLatest, then it works.